# changes in java code do not appear, program runs from a shell script

Tags: java, shell, github, intellij-idea, classpath

I cloned a GitHub repository (https://github.com/tomergreenwald/tac-adx) and did some changes in the code. But if i run the application with the runServer script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Usage
#   sh ./runServer.sh
#
TACAA_HOME=`pwd`
echo $TACAA_HOME
echo $CLASSPATH

java -cp "lib/*" se.sics.tasim.sim.Main
```

and the runAgent script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Usage
#   sh ./runServer.sh
#
TACAA_HOME=`pwd`
echo $TACAA_HOME
echo $CLASSPATH

java -cp "lib/*" tau.tac.adx.agentware.Main -config config/aw-1.conf
```

no changes appear. The program starts the simulation as if nothing had changed. I already tried to do some substantial code changes in the Main methods, like comment out everything, but it seems like the application is not using them.

How can i make my changes appear? (i use intelliJ as IDE)

Comment: You don't mention how you recompiled...

Comment: I didn’t recompile it

Comment: So why would you expect edits to the source code to make any difference if you did not recompile?

Comment: I didn’t know i had to do this. How do i recompile it properly?

Comment: I don't know IntelliJ so can't say. I would have guessed that auto recompile would be in force. If so, if it isn't recompiling then you haven't added the project properly to the ide

Comment: Also make sure that you import the project correctly. The project directory is called 'AdX' so should be the root of the Maven project

Comment: I have ```java -version
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)```

Answer (score 0):

I have `java -version`

```sh
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and `mvn -version`

```sh
Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 11.0.15, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.4.0-99-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

running and `mvn clean install` in directory `cd AdX` returns a lot of working tests and two failures such that the whole build seems to fail. Probably minor fixes.
In IntelliJ you probably need to define the actual maven source folder as a "source" (I think in that IDE it then shows as a blue folder). No idea, however, whether there is more logic around the build with this server invocation script.